# Scraping information from website using beautifullsoup wont work

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web

I have been using beautiful soup to extract info from the website http://slc.bioparadigms.org

But I am only interested in the diseases and OMIM number, so for each SLC transporter which i already have in a list i want to extract these 2 characteristics. The thing is that both are related to class prt_col2. So if i search for this class i get a lot of hits. How can I only get the diseases? Also sometimes there are no diseases related to the SLC transporter or sometimes there is no OMIM number. How can i extract the information? I put some screenshots below to show you how it looks like. Any help will be highly appreciated! This is my first post here so forgive me for any mistakes or missing information. Thank you!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyDuM.jpg other one is /L65HSym

So ideally the output will be for example:

transporter: SLC1A1

Disease: Epilepsy

OMIM: 12345

Edit: the code i have so far:

```
import os
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests
import sys
import time


def hasNumbers(inputString):                            #get transporter names which contain numbers
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)

def get_list(file):                                     #get a list of transporters
    transporter_list=[]
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(file)]
    for line in lines:
        if 'SLC' in line and hasNumbers(line) == True:
            get_SLC=line.split()
            if 'SLC' in get_SLC[0]:
                transporter_list.append(get_SLC[0])
    return transporter_list

def get_transporter_webinfo(transporter_list):
    output_Website=open("output_website.txt", "w")                                 # get the website content of all transporters
    for transporter in transporter_list:
        text = requests.get('http://slc.bioparadigms.org/protein?GeneName=' + transporter).text
        output_Website.write(text) #ouput from the SLC tables website         
        soup=BS(text, "lxml")
        disease = soup(text=re.compile('Disease'))
        characteristics=soup.find_all("span", class_="prt_col2")
        memo=soup.find_all("span", class_='expandable prt_col2')
        print(transporter,disease,characteristics[6],memo)

def convert(html_file):
    file2= open(html_file, 'r')
    clean_file= open('text_format_SLC','w')
    soup=BS(file2,'lxml')
    clean_file.write(soup.get_text())
    clean_file.close()

def main():

    start_time=time.time()
    os.chdir('/home/Programming/Fun stuff')
    sys.stdout= open("output_SLC.txt","w")
    SLC_list=get_list("SLC.txt")
    get_transporter_webinfo(SLC_list)                         #already have the website content so little redundant
    print("this took",time.time() - start_time, "seconds to run")
    convert("output_SLC.txt")
    sys.stdout.close() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No offence intended, I didn't feel like reading such a large piece of code as what you put in your question.

I would say it can be simplified.

You can get the complete list of links to the SLCs in the line at `SLCs =`. The next line shows how many there are, and the line beyond that exhibits the `href` attribute that the last link contains, as an example.

In each SLC's page I look for the string 'Disease' and then, if it's there, I navigate to the link nearby. I find the OMIM in a similar way.

Notice that I process only the first SLC.

```
>>> import requests
>>> import bs4
>>> main_url = 'http://slc.bioparadigms.org/'
>>> main_page = requests.get(main_url).content
>>> main_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(main_page, 'lxml')
>>> stem_url = 'http://slc.bioparadigms.org/protein?GeneName=SLC1A1'
>>> SLCs = main_soup.select('td.slct.tbl_cell.tbl_col1 a')
>>> len(SLCs)
418
>>> SLCs[-1].attrs['href']
'protein?GeneName=SLC52A3'
>>> stem_url = 'http://slc.bioparadigms.org/'
>>> for SLC in SLCs:
...     SLC_page = requests.get(stem_url+SLC.attrs['href'], 'lxml').content
...     SLC_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(SLC_page, 'lxml')
...     disease = SLC_soup.find_all(string='Disease: ')
...     if disease:
...         disease = disease[0]
...         diseases = disease.findParent().findNextSibling().text.strip()
...     else:
...         diseases = 'No diseases'
...     OMIM = SLC_soup.find_all(string='OMIM:')
...     if OMIM:
...         OMIM = OMIM[0]
...         number = OMIM.findParent().findNextSibling().text.strip()
...     else:
...         OMIM = 'No OMIM'
...         number = -1
...     SLC.text, number, diseases
...     break
... 
('SLC1A1', '133550', "Huntington's disease, epilepsy, ischemia, Alzheimer's disease, Niemann-Pick disease, obsessive-compulsive disorder")
```

Comment: If this, or any other, answer meets your requirements you should, please, mark it 'accepted'.

Comment: Thanks for your help, It is highly appreciated. I am a newbie in programming so i have to learn a lot. I was wondering if the script could be improved because I am also interested in the text shown in the class <span class="expandable prt_col2"> and especially in the text which starts with "Defects in ..... etc etc". So a little explanation of the disease. I tried to implement it myself but I get stuck and cannot do the same, findPartent().findNextSibling() trick you did with the disease and OMIM number. Hope you can help out with this one too. Thank you for teaching me.

Comment: You're very welcome. Because you asked your question on SO I naturally thought of it as a practical problem you were trying to solve, rather than a learning exercise. People do learn on SO (I do!) but we focus on specific questions. If you want people to discuss your code then you should probably move to Code Golf. Discussions are actually discouraged here. Best of luck!